# can we install multiple application using single wildcard App ID in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios5, development-environment, wildcard, iphone-developer-program

I have create three developer profile (like A,B,C) with wildcard APP ID.

First, I have install application A using profile A in device.

Now, I have install application B using profile B in device, then this B application is overwrite on application A. means now application A is not available in device only B application is available.

Same issue generate when we use C profile.

So, only one application is install in device at a time that's my problem.

so. pls tell me how to install more than one application in device without generated different APP ID(means using wildcard APP ID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that all of your apps are using the same bundle identifier (specified in the app's info.plist file)..

The idea is:

1. each app has got its own unique identifier;
2. a (`*`) wildcard profile will just work with any identifier.

A bundle identifier has the generic form:

```
domain.name.appName
```

e.g.

```
com.apple.iphoto
```

I would suggest checking how those values are defined in your apps.